# AngularJs cannot read property "UpdateTime" of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following js controller:

```
angular.module('gtApp').controller('settingsController', ["$scope", function($scope, SincService) {
    $scope.CallTime = 5;
    $scope.$watch('CallTime', function() {
        SincService.UpdateTime(CallTime);
    });    
}]);
```

and the following factory:

```
angular.module('gtApp').factory('SincService', function ($rootScope) {
    var data = {};

    data.CallTime = 5;

    data.UpdateTime = function(value) {
        this.CallTime = value;
        $rootScope.$broadcast("timeUpdated");
    }

    return data;
});
```

I want to call the UpdateTime method from the js controller when the CallTime variable changes in controller but I receive this: `Cannot read property 'UpdateTime' of undefined`. I already searched and read a lot of posts on this error but I cannot find what I'm doing wrong. Please give me some help with this :) .

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare a service injection in array notation. It should be:

```
angular.module('gtApp').controller('settingsController', ["$scope", "SincService", function($scope, SincService) {
    $scope.CallTime = 5;
    $scope.$watch('CallTime', function() {
        SincService.UpdateTime(CallTime);
    });    
}]);
```

Note `"SincService"` string as the second element of the controller definition array.

Answer (score 0):

`CallTime` should be either `newVal` from watch function or `$scope.CallTime`, also missed to add dependency of `SincService`

```
angular.module('gtApp').controller('settingsController',["$scope",'SincService', function($scope, SincService) {
    $scope.CallTime = 5;
    $scope.$watch('CallTime', function(newVal) {
        SincService.UpdateTime(newVal);
    });    
}]);
```